# updated HTC one mini screen black

Tags: screen

I just updated my HTC one Mini and the bottom half of the screen is now black. Why? I have not done anything to it

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'updated'? We need more information to be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

it happens.Don't worry, its just a minor brick. you can recover it. What you have to do is, you have to flash your htc mini with a new firmware(either stock/cyanogenmod/any custom rom). But proceed by your own risk. Now follow up how to flash custom rom/cyanogenmod/ stock rom on htc mini on google. You should find your answer.

Good Luck!

Comment: But before that, just go to recovery mod and do these **wipe data/factory reset and wipe delvic cache** that may also solve your problem.